# Ignore linebreaks when searching for patterns with bash

Tags: bash, sed, line-breaks

I have files with constant stream of letters, capped at 10 letters per line, like so:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXABCDEF
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

I want to remove the Xs in groups of three, so I want the result to be

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
XABCDEF
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

My current approach is

```
sed 's/XXX//g' inputFile > outputFile
```

but that only considers the pattern within a single line, and results in:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
X
X
X
XABCDEF
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

How do I need to formulate the search pattern to ignore linebreaks, so to essentially accept XXX, X\nXX, and XX\nX? Is this possible with sed, or another command?

Comment: Assume a line `ABCDEFGHXX` followed by `XABCDEFGHI`. Should the output a single line with the content `ABCDEFGHABCDEFGHI` or two lines; `ABCDEFGH` followed by `ABCDEFGHI` ?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed. Modify your regex.

```
sed -zE 's/X\n{0,1}X\n{0,1}X\n{0,1}//g' inputFile > outputFile
```

Or shorter:

```
sed -zE 's/(X\n?){3}//g' inputFile > outputFile
```

Output to `outputFile`:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
XABCDEF
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

> `-z`: separate lines by NUL characters

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
paste -sd '' your_file | sed 's/XXX/   /g' | fold -w 10 | sed 's/ //g; /^$/d'
```

- `paste -sd '' your_file` merges all the lines onto a single line
- `sed 's/XXX/   /g'` replaces three X's by three spaces (note this will be
  problematic if the original file has spaces, since in the last step I remove
  them all... you could choose some other unique replacement if this is the
  case).
- `fold -w 10` folds the long line back to a set of lines 10 characters long
- `sed 's/ //g; /^$/d'` removes the spaces and the removes any blank lines (if
  you used some other unique replacement instead of spaces in the second step,
  remove *that* instead of spaces in this step).

Outputs

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
XABCDEF
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

Comment: I wondered whether creating a single long line would cause problems if there were a huge number of lines in the file, so I tried out this answer with a file containing 10 million lines (105Mb) and it took just over 9 seconds and completed normally (so I guess a lot of lines isn't too problematic).

Comment: The other problem with doing that is that as soon as you remove all newlines the result is no longer a valid text file per POSIX and so YMMV with what any text processing tool will do with it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -zE 's/(X|X\n){3}//g' file
```

or without the `-z` slurp option:

```
sed -E 'H;$!d;x;s/^\n|(X|X\n){3}//g' file
```